# Apple wallet relevantDate not able to get notified

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile-development, passkit, apple-wallet

I was trying to get shown up on lock screen in Iphone based on the relevantDate attribute in pass.json, but it was unable to get shown. can someone help me if i miss any anything or any mandatory attribute.

even i tried unpack pkpass and see what pass.json contains its in expected format

before converting to pkpass, json has

"relevantDate" : "2023-09-28T22:00:00+02:00" after conversion it pkpass of pass json has
"relevantDate" : "2023-09-28T20:00:00.000Z". i live in utc+2 timezone. so gave that format

```
{
  "passTypeIdentifier" : "pass.com.xxxxxx.xxxxxxx",  
  "formatVersion" : 1,
  "teamIdentifier" : "xxxxxx",
  "organizationName" : "xxxxxxx Company",
  "relevantText" : "xxxxxxxx",  
  "relevantDate" : "2023-09-28T22:00:00+02:00",
  "description" : "xxxxxxxx",
  "foregroundColor" : "rgb(0, 0, 0)",
  "backgroundColor" : "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
  "labelColor" : "rgb(0, 0, 0)",
  "serialNumber" : "xxxxxx",
  "barcodes" : [{
          "format" : "PKBarcodeFormatQR",
          "message" : "xxxxxxxx",
          "altText" : "xxxxxxxxx"
   }],
  "generic" : {
      "headerFields" : []
      ,
    "primaryFields" : [
      {
        "key" : "customer",
        "label" : "xxxxxxx",
        "value" : "xxxxxxx"
      }
    ],
    "secondaryFields" : [
      {
        "key" : "service",
        "label" : "yyyyyyyy",
        "value" : "yyyyyy",
        "textAlignment":"PKTextAlignmentLeft"
      }
    ],
    "auxiliaryFields" : [
      {
        "key" : "datetime",
        "label" : "Date&Time",
        "value" : "xxxxxxxx",
        "textAlignment": "PKTextAlignmentLeft"
      }
     
    ],
    "backFields" : []
  }
}
```

Expecting that apple get shows the pass on lock screen when relevantDate is set

Comment: Why do you believe that setting `relevantDate` will result in a notification? The device may show this pass in siri widgets or on the Lock Screen based on this date, but it won't post a notification

Comment: @Paulw11, Sorry, yes i mean showing it on the lock screen when its relevant on a date, its unable to show up

Comment: Did you test on a simulator? [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/walletpasses/pass/showing_a_pass_on_the_lock_screen) indicate that you must test on a device.

Comment: Yes it did work based on relevantDate attribute